# How to run a Prolog/Datalog program where facts can be added interactively

Tags: prolog, datalog

I hope my question makes sense. I wasn't sure how it should be expressed. My apologies if it does not.

Suppose I have a Prolog query such as

```
ancestor(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y).
ancestor(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y), ancestor(Z, Y).
```

Now I want to run some web app or api that will allow me to add facts interactively. Perhaps like

```
POST /facts {"fact": "parent(beatrix, charlie)."}
```

Perhaps at some later point, I want to run the `ancestor` query, again via the api:

```
GET /ancestor {"x": "beatrix", "y": "charlie"}
```

which now hopefully returns true (or something similar).

Does anyone have some ideas of how this can be accomplished? Either in Prolog or Datalog? Or some Prolog wrapper like https://github.com/ichiban/prolog.

From what I have read so far it seems I need to `:- dynamic parent/2` and keep adding facts with `?- assertz(parent(beatrix, charlie)).` but surely there is a better way? Maybe this is where something like Datalog would shine? But I don't know much about Datalog yet.

Anyway, I would be greatful for any hints or links to reading material.

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of X, Y and Z, the likes of Child, Parent, Grandparent, or even Younger, Elder etc. as variable names would be clearer.

Comment: "*surely there is a better way?*" - what is wrong with that way? What would be 'better' about another way? You will need some code to add a fact, `assertz()` seems as good as any, no?

Comment: After a weekend of hacking around and reading others' code, I agree with you. `assertz()` seems like the way to go. Thank you for confirming as well!

Comment: An alternative in swi-prolog is: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=gvar